# Adicionar valor a uma lista de strings

Tags: c#, .net, string, lista, asp.net-core

Eu tenho uma classe, e nela eu tenho uma `List<string>` e eu apenas a crio para adicionar os valores em outro lugar. Mas quando eu tento adicionar um valor, recebo o seguinte erro:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Vou deixar um exemplo mais claro de como estou fazendo:

Classe com a lista:

```
public class cl{
    public List<string> dados { get; set; }
}
```

Adicionando valor à lista:

```
public IActionResult OnPost(cl c){
    c.dados.Add("teste");
}
```

A partir daí eu recebo o erro que deixei acima.

Estou usando o .Net Core Razor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa criar uma instância da sua `List`.
Você pode fazer assim:

```
public List<string> dados { get; set; } = new List<string>();
```

O código acima cria uma instância da `List` de `strings`, sendo assim, seu objeto estará acessível, isto é, devidamente instanciado e pronto para uso.
E seu problema estará resolvido.

Classes em C# não são automaticamente inicializadas. Sendo assim, você sempre precisa inicializá-las de alguma forma, diferente de `structs`, por exemplo, que são `não-nuláveis` por padrão.

Se a sua `List` só vai ser inicializada dentro dessa `classe` e não mudar, você pode por ela como apenas `get`:

```
public List<string> dados { get; } = new List<string>();
```

Comment: Boa Kevin. Mas e no caso de eu querer dar o valor a uma certa linha dessa lista? Por exemplo `c.dados[0] = "bb"`, quando eu tento fazer isso, ainda dá erro. Eu preciso fazer um `.Add()` primeiro pra depois utilizar o `c.dados[0]`?

Comment: Sim, a lista começa vazia, ou seja, o indice 0 ainda nem existe, não há como acessá-lo. Se você quer acessar um índice diretamente, o ideal é você checar o tamanho antes, com `.Length`. Talvez a `List` não seja ideal para você, dependendo do que você quer fazer.

Answer (score 4):

Note que na sua classe `cl` você diz que existe uma lista de strings chamada de `dados` mas você não iniciou ela. Ao criar esta classe, esta lista existe mas é nula até você a instanciar.

Antes da sua linha `c.dados.Add("teste");` apenas faça: `c.dados = new List<string>();` e isto deve resolver seu problema.

Outra opção seria criar um construtor para sua classe `cl` e neste construtor instanciar a lista:

```
public class cl{
    public List<string> dados { get; set; }

    public cl() {
       dados = new List<string>();
   }
}
```